# Thunderbird folder layout and/or namespaces for gmail

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, imap

Short version: I want Thunderbird to show me gmail's "All Mail" label (and nothing else, not even the Inbox).

Long version: Here's the default folder layout in Thunderbird for a gmail account:

- address

  - Inbox
  - [...]
  - [Gmail]

    - [...]
    - All Mail
    - [...]
    - Starred

Here's what I want:

- address

  - All Mail (from [Gmail] above)
  - Trash

How do I do this?  Are there any gotchas to doing this (e.g. mail read/unread status getting updated incorrectly, offline-caching getting done incorrectly, etc.)?

Thanks, folks!

Moy

Edit: Account Settings -> Server Settings -> Advanced -> IMAP server directory = "[Gmail]" solves the hierarchy problem (i.e. it moves "All Mail" up one level), but it still shows "[Gmail]" in the folder list and I still cannot get rid of the main Inbox folder. I suspect this is a namespace issue but I don't know enough about IMAP to say.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click any folder listed under the account and click **Subscribe**
2. Uncheck the folders you don't want to be displayed in Thunderbird.

> Messages will still be downloaded and available through the "All Mail" folder. They will also be included in search results. However, the Gmail label (Thunderbird folder) will not be displayed.

See [Subscribing to or unsubscribing from folders (labels)](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-gmail?s=subscribe&as=s#w_subscribing-to-or-unsubscribing-from-folders-labels)

Comment: Thanks, but this has two problems: (a) One cannot get rid of the Inbox this way, and (b) one cannot change the hierarchy as my diagram shows.